# updating displayname of user in firebase (android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a project with firebase for login screen. I am trying to update the displayName of user with the code below but it is not updating the display name. Help me out

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(name)
                .build();
        user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(VerifyUser.this,"Name updated successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(VerifyUser.this,MainActivity.class));
                }else
                    Toast.makeText(VerifyUser.this,"Name update Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, So I use Firebase admin SDK to change the displayName

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the user profile right after a log-in or a verification of email and password.

I know I am late, but for posterity, for one to update a user attributes on firebase, they need to login first.

so something like :

```
 mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LordRegister.this,
                    new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                //verification successful we will start the profile activity
                                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                                String name = nameInput.getText().toString().trim();
                                //user.updateProfile()
                                UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                        .setDisplayName(name)
                                        .build();
                                user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(LordRegister.this, LordHome.class);
                                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }else
                                            Toast.makeText(LordRegister.this,"Name update Failed, try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });

                            } else {

                                //verification unsuccessful.. display an error message

                                String message = "Somthing is wrong, we will fix it soon...";

                                if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                    message = "Invalid code entered...";
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(LordRegister.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
}
```

Like above I'm using a user phoneNumber to sign-in or rather to verify a user first, then updating the name or any other attribute.